# search in sharepoint list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I need to implement search in a SharePoint 2013 site home page where in the search results should be probably from a list with list name `ListA` (with column name Project Name and Project Category).
The search results should only be from the two columns mentioned above.
Once the search results appear, after selecting a particular search result it should re-direct to its particular details page(`Projectdetails.aspx`)

We're trying to use `jQuery/REST` API in SharePoint Designer 2013.

Please let me know for any further information.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I wanted to know how to implement the above scenario

Answer (score 1):

If you need an Idea to do that, you can do the following:

> **Create HTML Design in a txt file**

- This includes creating html for Search input box or any other controls, search button and a div to show search results.
- Upload this file somewhere on the site (e.g. Style library/html)
  -

> **Write Javascript**

- Write Javascript to perform validation.
- Write click event for search button. Use JSOM to retrieve list items based on a CAML Query that takes the input from controls and retrieves list items based on user specified values.
- In success handler of your function, retrieve id's for matched items, and use these
  id's to create dynamic html to redirect to display form (Details) of the item e.g. (`<a href="https://serverurl/lists/yourlist/DispForm.aspx?ID=[id-of-matched-item]"><span>[Item's Title]</span></a>`)
- Populate the div (that you created in html) with dynamic html (e.g. $('#yourdivid').html(dynamicHTML));
- upload this JS file on somewhere on your site (e.g.Style Library/JS)
- refer this JS file in your HTML

> **Create Content Editor Webpart**

Go to the page where you want to put your search control and edit the page. Insert a Content editor webpart, and in webpart's configurations, refer the txt (html) file then save the page.
hope this helps

**EDIT** : To retrieve items from a list using CAML query, you can use JSOM

```
function GetSearchResults() {  //search button click handler
// Get textboxes' text.. 'tboxProjectName' and 'tboxProjectCategories' are id's that you assign to textboxes in your html.
var projectNameVal = $('#tboxProjectName').val();
var projectCategoryVal = $('#tboxProjectCategory').val();
//Get SP Context
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ListA");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //you can modify query text according to your data types and applying operators different than <Contains> e.g. <Eq>, <Lt>, <Gt> etc.
    var camlText = '<View><Query><Where><Or><Contains><FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Name"/><Value Type="Text">' + projectNameVal +'</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Category"/><Value Type="Text">' + projectCategoryVal +'</Value></Contains></Or></Where></Query></View>';
camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlText);
this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(getResultsSuccess,onFailure);
}

function getResultsSuccess() {
    var listItem;
    var html = '';
    var dispFormUrl = "https://yourserver.com/lists/lista/dispform.aspx?ID="
    var listEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        html += '<a href = "'+dispFormurl+listItem.get_item("ID")+'"><span>'+listItem.get_item("Title")+'</a> <br />'

}
$('#yourdivID').html(html)
    }
function onFailure(sender,args)
{
 alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: A sample code would be really helpful, am a beginner in coding, hope you understand. I've never worked with CAML Query

Comment: I have added the code in my answer, might need to be modified a bit to adapt to your needs.

Comment: @Murad Haider- There is an error encountered at var context line, it says "Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined"
And I've question in the CAML Query, you've mentioned 'projectNameVal'  and 'projectCategoryVal', are these the values which we provide in the text box?If so, do we need them to initialize anywhere?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've added SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', GetSearchResults); before the function, but still the error exists

Comment: 'projectNameVal' and 'projectCategoryVal' are supposed to be variables that will eventually get the values of your textboxes,  you can create/initialize these variables in search button click handler. and for 'undefined' error, you need to ensure that necessary JS files are loaded by SharePoint before you get the client context. For this you can make SharePoint load scripts on demand:
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {
  yourseachfunction();
  });
 use this in your click handler

Comment: My function name is 'GetSearchResults'..
In html I gave this way:
<button onclick="GetSearchResults()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                <div id="yourdivID"></div>

Now, for where should I create/initialize 'projectNameVal', 'projectCategoryVal' variables?

And for 'undefined' error, do I need download sp.js reference file? I cannot find the sp.js reference file to download...

Am a beginner in SharePoint, that's the reason am facing these issues, hope you understand.. Thank you

Comment: No worries, everyone faces such issues, good thing is that you are giving this a try. you don't need to download sp.js, SharePoint loads this by itself you just need to use SP.SOD.executeFunc the way i told in my last comment. check edited code for variables.

Comment: Am getting the error as below:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isNullOrUndefined' of undefined
    at new SP.ClientContext (sp.js:2)
    at new SP.ClientContext.get_current (sp.js:2)
    at GetSearchResults (Home.js:62)
    at EnsureScript (init.js?rev=Xpo7ARBt8xBROO1h5n3s6g%3D%3D:1)
    at Object.EnsureScriptFunc [as executeFunc] (init.js?rev=Xpo7ARBt8xBROO1h5n3s6g%3D%3D:1)
    at Home.js:59

Comment: the functionality should be in such a way that whenever an input is given in the text box, the results should be displayed on other page, that page has a query string in the below way:
http://ecfd13.xxx.com/sites/abc-dev/Pages/ProjectDetails.aspx?PId=29&category=All

Comment: Can anyone provide a solution for the above requirement please?

Comment: do you want to pick the values from the query string rather than textboxes?

Comment: When an input is given in text box(the input will have a specific Id which is present in the query string), based on the id of the query string the page should be displayed.

Comment: If you want to view results on a different page, then you can send your control values in query string parameters e.g PID and category and on 'results' page you can include JS to get values from query string and retrieve list items/documents based on those values, and display results on a div in that page

Comment: how can I send control values in query string parameters e.g PID and category?

Comment: var url = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/[pages library]/[your page].aspx? PID = [project id control value]&Category=[Category-control-value]";      
window.location.href = url;

Comment: What should I give in place of [project id control value]?

Comment: I don't know why my text box value is not binding, I mean when I enter some value in text box and debug, the text box is showing as empty..Can I share my code, so that you can take a look? I'm unable to share it here, since it is long

Comment: here is my html code:
<input style="width:259px;float:left" type="text" class="form-control" id="tboxProjectName" placeholder="Search..">
                                <button onclick="GetSearchResults()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

Comment: this line : var projectNameVal = $('#tboxProjectName').val(); replace this with
this.projectNameVal = $('#tboxProjectName').val(); as success handler is out of parent function. then in success function you need to replace query string param value with this variable i.e. var url = "yoursite/pages/projectdetails.aspx?PID=" +projectNameVal+"&category=All"
you can use variable for 'category' same way.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the textbox value is empty

Comment: My question in this line:var url = "yoursite/pages/projectdetails.aspx?PID=" +projectNameVal+"&category=All" is the project id is a number, but we give text in textbox, right? Can we include that in querystring, since the querystring filters with id(number)

Comment: sure, please share your gmail id

Comment: on which page you are trying to get textboxes value, you need to fetch textboxes value in the js associated with the page that contains your textbox, then send the value in querystring, the results page will contain js to extract the value from query string and js code to get results from SP